# How do I make the section text in capital letters?

Tags: titles, titletoc, sans-serif, uppercase

How to format the section with capital letters and leave the TOC text in normal format.

I want to use this command:

`\section{Section Text}`

with the result similar to this:

`\section[Section Text]{\MakeUppercase{Section Text}}`

I'm using the following section configuration:

`\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{\centering\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries}}%`

To get a result of this type:

Contents

1. Section Text . . . . . page number
2. ...

1  SECTION TEXT

text text text. I would like to use the section title in sans serif font and uppercase.

is it possible?

Comment: Have you looked into [tag:titletoc]'s companion [tag:titlesec]?

Comment: just put `\MakeUppercase` in `\section` def. Like: `\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}{\centering\normalfont\sffamily\bfseries\MakeUppercase}}`

Answer (score 1):

While you can certainly do it other ways, I find it easiest to use the titlesec package to customize headings and its companion titletoc to customize TOC entries; see [the documentation](https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}% package for customizing headings
\usepackage{titletoc}% package for customizing the toc
\titleformat{\section}% the command you want to format
    {\bfseries\sffamily\MakeUppercase}% the style/commands applied to entire title
    {\thesection}% format of the number label; here just the number
    {0.5em}% spacing after the number
    {}% additional styles applied to just the title itself

\dottedcontents{section}% level of toc you want to customize
    [1em]% spacing on left of number
    {}% code before each section entry
    {1em}% width of section number in toc
    {1pc}% spacing between dots


\titlecontents{section}% level of toc you want to customize
    [1em]% spacing to the left where titles start
    {}% code applied before entry
    {\thecontentslabel. }%formatting of numbered entry labels
    {}% format of unnumbered entry labels
    {\dotfill\rlap{\makebox[1em][r]{\thecontentspage}}}% formatting after the title
    {}% filler

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Second Section}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]